# Logstash Elastic Cloud 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-cloud

[Official logstash elastic cloud module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/connecting-to-cloud.html)

[Official doc for starting with](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/saas-release/ec-cloud-id.html)

My `logstash.yml` looks like:

```
  cloud.id: "Test:testkey"
  cloud.auth: "elastic:password"
```

With 2 spaces in front and no space at end, within `""`

This is all I have in `logstash.yml` and nothing else, 
And I am getting:

`[2018-08-29T12:33:52,112][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"https://myserverurl:12345/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :error=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://myserverurl:12345/'"}`

And the `my_config_file_name.conf` looks like:

```
input{jdbc{...jdbc here... This works, as I see data in windows console}}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["myserverurl:12345"]
    index => "my_index"
    # document_id => "%{brand}"
    }
```

What I am doing is hitting `bin/logstash` on windows `cmd`, 
It loads data from database that I have configured in input of conf file and then shows me error, I want to index my data from `MySQL` to `elasticsearch` on Cloud, I took 14 days trial and created a test index, for learning purpose as I later have to deploy it.
My Pipeline looks like:

```
  - pipeline.id: my_id
    path.config: "./config/conf_file_name.conf"
    pipeline.workers: 1
```

If logs won't include senistive data, I can also provide them.

Basically I wan't to sync (schedule check) my `MYSQL` data with `ElasticSearch` on cloud i.e. `AWS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shall be:

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://yourhost:yourport/"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "password"
    # protocol => https
    # port => "yourport"
    index => "test_index"
    # document_id => "%{table_id}"
```

`#` - represent comments
as stated at: [Configuring logstash with elastic cloud docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-logstash.html)

The document provided while deploying app does not provide config for jdbc, jdbc as well need user and password even if defined in settings file i.e. `logstash.yml`

Answer (score 2):

Also if you created your API key in the web UI you will not be able to get the values needed to configure Logstash. You **must** to use the devtool console found at /app/dev_tools#/console with something like this:

```
POST /_security/api_key
{
  "name": "logstash"
}
```

of which the output is something like:

```
{
  "id": "<id value>",
  "name": "logstash",
  "api_key": "<api key>",
  "encoded": "<encoded api key>"
}
```

And in your logstash pipeline config you use the values like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    cloud_id => "<cloud id>"
    api_key => "<id value>:<api key>"
    data_stream => true
    ssl => true
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Note the combined "api_key" value separated by ":". Also, you can find the "cloud id" under your "Deployments" menu option.

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue in my dev environment. After scour hours on google, I understood by default, when you install Logstash, X-Pack is installed. In the doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/setup-xpack.html it is stated that

> Blockquote

X-Pack is an Elastic Stack extension that provides security, alerting, monitoring, machine learning, pipeline management, and many other capabilities

> Blockquote

As I don't need x-pack to run in my dev while I am streaming Elasticsearch, I had to disable it by setting **ilm_enabled** to false in the output of my indexation file configuration.

```
    output {
     elasticsearch { 
        hosts =>  [.. ]
        ilm_enabled => false
      }
    }
```

The link bellow may help
https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/logstash-oss-with-non-removable-x-pack/655/3